# Group by several terms and limit in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grouping, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index which is like this (giving an abstract example)

```
{"name": "John", "district": 1, "lastName": "Smith"},
{"name": "Anne", "district": 1, "lastName": "Smith"},
{"name": "Mary", "district": 2, "lastName": "Smith"},
{"name": "Bobby", "district": 2, "lastName": "Smith"},
{"name": "Nick", "district": 1, "lastName": "Smith"},
{"name": "Bob", "district": 3, "lastName": "Smith"},
{"name": "Kenny", "district": 1, "lastName": "Smith"}
```

I want to do something SQL-like `GROUP BY name, district, lastName LIMIT 100` but in elastic search.

I thought that I would need to use the `terms` aggregation nested (terms aggs inside terms aggs inside terms aggs).

But I want to limit all the grouped results to 100 (and not e.g 100 per district)

How can this be reached? Is there a way to do this without needing to query more than what we need?

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter or define size in aggregations like

```
"aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "ATTRIBUTES.ATTR_TYPE": "EDUCATION_DEGREE"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "ATTRIBUTES.DESCRIPTION",
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how are u doing it can u share ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) starting from Elasticsearch 6.1. You can define [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_size) parameter to limit buckets to 100.

Hope that helps!